# Diff applications going crazy if the functions in the file were reordered

Tags: c#, windows, diff

I've been busy refactoring a file in our project and as part of my changes I reordered the function to a more logical way. However, now when I'm trying to review my changes I get a mess: The diff applications has no idea that the functions were merely reordered and marks 80% of the file content as changed.

I've tried to see the diff with both "Beyond Compare" and "WinMerge" to the same result.
Is there some setting that might help me here?

As tagged, I am using C# on Windows.

Comment: Is there an ignore whitespace option? Might be down to tabs vs. spaces.

Comment: if you started the refactoring with ONLY re-ordering functions (i.e. no actual changes), then you should be confident of your change.

Comment: @Alex: Yes there is, but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: @Mitch: True, it is what I will do if there is no other way. Just seems a shame.

Comment: Consider this refactoring case: 1) Reordered methods (e.g. grouped related functionality), 2) Split up large class into separate files (using `partial class` syntax, in my case it's a large data access object), and 3) Modified methods (wrote a generic method that removed 90% of the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeyondCompare (and probably other tools as well) has a feature where you can choose a line and select which line in the other file to use as a reference. That way you can at least compare each method one by one. Depending on how many methods you have this might be an option. However it still requires some manual and probably tedious work.

The other way simply would be to rearrange the methods without changing anything and checking it in. Then once you have the rearranged class you can use a diff tool for any changes you make within each method.

Answer (score 2):

Traditional text differences are based only in textual content. For this reason you see the 80% of the file content as changed.

[Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com) has a smart differencer called **XDiff**. It's able to find differences in moved or refactored code. Take a look to [this post](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/07/move-support-in-diff.html) to learn more about XDiff. It works also for [merge](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmerge-to-merge-refactored-code.html) support.

[Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com) is a complete SCM solution. You can install it and use only the diff/merge tool.

Comment: I've installed Plastic SCM, but I don't see the "XDiff" binary you mentioned. Do you mean "binmergetool.exe" perhaps?

Comment: @VitalyB: The diff/merge tool is mergetool.exe. The XDiff is only a feature. You can launch it and select the files manually. But you can also authomatize the process. It works as a diff tool when you pass two arguments (left and right files), and a merge tool if you pass 4 arguments (source, destination, base, result file). The binmergetool.exe is the binary merge tool. Is used to manage diffs/merges between images and binary files.

Comment: Give a try to Method History: http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/method-history-for-subversion-is-here.html

Comment: Didn't work for me -- I wasn't able to compare reordered chunks. Looked the same as all the other diff tools.  Ran macmergetool on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a tool that understands code structures (expressions, statements, declaration, functions) and the kinds of operations you do to them: insert, delete, move, copy, copy-and-rename, etc.   You sound like you've done a bunch of "code moves".
Textual diff programs by definition can't do this.

Our [Smart Differencer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) can do this for many languages: C#, C++, COBOL, Java, PHP, ...
It reports differences in terms of language constructs, and is precise to the line/column.

Comment: @Joe White: Well, there *is* a pricing page easily found from the site pulldown menus.  There *was* a glitch on the pricing page regarding Smart Differencer pricing; that's fixed now.

Comment: @Vitaly: There's a "downloads" link on the Products tab on the web page.

Comment: Okay, I finally found the pricing, buried in the middle of the mile-long "Pricing" page. (Don't you think it'd be better to have a separate pricing page for each product?)

Comment: @Joe White: There's a link to the Smart Differencer section of that page, at the top of the page.

Comment: The cost is about $250.00 at present, so a lot more then other diff tools

Comment: True.  But none of the other diff tools have any understanding of language syntax. If you don't mind wading through unnecessarily big deltas, you can stick to the cheaper alternatives.  If you do mind, you have a judgement call to make.  The issue you should judge a tool by is how much of your time does it save, and what that is that worth to you, not its raw cost.  Otherwise we'd all be using stones instead of hammers.

Comment: Downloaded this today and installed it.  I can't find any documentation on how to integrate it as an external DIFF tool for a source repository browser (Tortoise SVN, TFS, etc).  Setting it up as a simple command-line tool going off of the "Usage" section of the documentation results in a command prompt window that simply opens and closes immediately without providing any useful feedback.

Comment: @Toby: Would you please send description of which SmartDiff you downloaded (version and for which language), your OS, and a screenshot of your command line invocation to "support@semanticdesigns.com".  We think this tool works :-{